# C++ how to avoid overriding virtual method from interface

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

I came from JVM world and I try to implement something in c++.

I have an interface:

```
class MyInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void my_method(std::string i) = 0;
        virtual void my_method(int i) = 0;
};
```

And I would like to have two subclasses A and B:

```
class AClass: public MyInterface
{
public:
    void my_method(std::string i); // And implement only that method in .c file
}
```

And class B:

```
public BClass: public MyInterface
{
public:
    void my_method(int i); // And implement only that method in .c file
}
```

But I got errors. (I cannot paste logs because I have production code only and the code above is only the scaffolding of the real problem). 
Is there any pattern to avoid overriding some virtual methods?

Comment: What do you want to happen when somebody does `myAInstance.my_method(1);`? Or `myBInstance.my_method("X");`? And what about `myInterfaceObject.my_method(1)`?

Comment: _@user_ Do you rather want an _abstract class_ implementation (with default behaviors) than a _pure virtual interface_?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any pattern to avoid overriding some virtual methods?

I don't think there is any pattern for that. You just have to make sure that all virtual member functions are implemented in the most derived class or one of its parent classes.

A trivial implementation is not too hard for the functions you have.

```
class AClass: public MyInterface
{
  public:

    void my_method(std::string i); // And implement only that method in .c file
    void my_method(int i) {}       // That's all you need
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child classes selectively override parent methods.
You need something like this :

```
class MyInterface // Consider a different name
{
    public:
        virtual void my_method(std::string i) {
        // Business Logic  . Let child 1 override this
        }
        virtual void my_method(int i) {
        // Business Logic . Let child 2 override this
        }
};
```

In short you can't have an abstract base here.

Comment: The question clearly intends to override the methods.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Hmm. Changed the solution.